# Why lots black dots when html page print using Bluetooth Mobile Printer?

Tags: printing, bluetooth

We have a Bluetooth Mobile printer and we needs to print a content using a html page.

HTML CODE:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body contenteditable="false" style="background-color: white;">
    <h1>HTML5 Canvas</h1>
    <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100" style="border:1px solid grey;"></canvas>
    <script>
      const canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
      const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      ctx.font = "30px Arial";
      ctx.fillText("Hello World", 10, 50);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How it looks like:

[image: HTML page]

Out put of the printer

[image: Print]

what is the reason for these lots of black dots?